# Should rest api backend on tomcat allow keepalive request?

Tags: spring, rest, tomcat, stateless

In current stateless backend, should tomcat servers allow keep alive request ? Or Should we terminate connection after each request by setting maxKeepAliveRequests to 1?

Answer (score 0):

I prefer **not** to set the **maxKeepAliveRequests value to 1** unless you've got the requirement for a highly concurrent environment.

Because when you are setting this attribute value to 1, this will disable HTTP/1.0 keep-alive, as well as HTTP/1.1 keep-alive and pipelining.
When using SSL,  HTTP keep-alive should be enabled as the SSL handshake is an expensive operation to perform for every request.

I prefer setting this attribute to the average number based on your requirement between 10 and 100.